# keep window from moving when displaying sticky nav

Tags: jquery, mobile, navigation

So I have a sticky header with a drop down menu for mobile phones on the site I am working on.

You can see what happens here, while having the window sized down to get the toggle button to show: http://www.revival.tv/turningpoint/

My problem is that I would like to have the menu stay there when toggling it, instead of having it scroll back to the top. Is this possible?

Here is my js handling the toggle:

```
$("#social-wrap li:nth-child(4)").click(function(){
   $("#phone-nav").slideToggle("slow");
});

$("#phone-nav a").click(function(){
   $("#phone-nav").slideUp("fast");
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the reason this is happening is because the anchor tag href is set to "#" which will default to the top of the page

```
<a href="#">m</a>
```

change that to

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)">m</a>
```

Comment: @ftntravis On side note, you can keep the # and use `preventDefault` instead. For e.g. `$("#phone-nav a").click(function(e){ e.preventDefault();$("#phone-nav").slideUp("fast");});`. This way you don't have to stuff all your links with `javascript:void(0)`